# adapter.Update first goes to the Rowupdated event before going into the catch block

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception, ado.net

I have this code for an `SqlDataAdapter`

```
adapter.RowUpdated += adapter_RowUpdated;
try
{
    try
    {
      adapter.Update(Table);
      trans.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       trans.Rollback();
       throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
finally
{
    adapter.RowUpdated -= adapter_RowUpdated;
}
```

and this is my Rowupdated event

```
void adapter_RowUpdated(object sender, SqlRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.StatementType == StatementType.Insert)
    {
       object ai = e.Command.Parameters["@SCOPE_ID"].Value;
       e.Row[_IdentityFieldName] = ai;
    }
}
```

This has worked well for over a year now.
But sometimes I get an exception "column xxxID cannot be null" when inserting, so I debugged it and the problems is that when the `adapter.Update(table)`fails (for example because a check constraint was violated) the next line of code is not the Catch code, but it first goes into the RowUpdated event.
In that event there off course occurs a new exception that the _IdentityFieldName can not be null (it holds the name of the primary field of the table, which is an identity field)

And only after that it goes into the catch, but at that time the original exception is replaced from `check constraint violated`to `column cannot be null`

**When I run/debug the following happens**

The application breaks at the `adapter.Update(table)` with exception

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint
>   "CK_PrijsAankoop". The conflict occurred in database "GTT_Test", table
>   "dbo.tblOpdrachtCar

Now I expect it to go into the catch, but it first goes into the adapter_RowUpdated event, and there another exception is thrown on the line `e.Row[IdentityFieldName] = ai;`

> OpdrachtCarID' does not allow nulls

And now it finally goes into the catch block, but the exception is now not the original exception anymore !

**So my question is**, how can I force dotnet to do correct exception handling and go to the catch straightaway without going to this event first ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. [`RowUpdated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.rowupdated?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) will raise after the attempt to update the row, regardless of success of failure. In fact, `RowUpdated` is specially useful for responding to the errors and exceptions that occur during the update.

The event argument of the event, [`SqlRowUpdatedEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlrowupdatedeventargs?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), has an [`Errors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.rowupdatedeventargs.errors?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property that you can use to get the errors that has been occurred during row update.

You can check the status of the execution using [`Status`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.rowupdatedeventargs.status?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property of the event argument:

```
if (e.Status == UpdateStatus.ErrorsOccurred)  
{  
    //An error occurred
}
```

To learn more about DataAdapter events, take a look at [Handling DataAdapter Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/handling-dataadapter-events).

Comment: OK so I can use this to known that an error occured and not do my code when an error occured. Thanks

Comment: In addition to the answer, I should mention, updating an `Identity` column value, can be done automatically by an output parameter or a SELECT command. To see how it can be done, create a `DataSet` in your project using *Data Source Window* and then open the data set in designer and click on a table adapter and see the INSERT command. It has a `SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE (Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY())` at the end.